# YouCompleteMe don't start complete past

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I've installed the plugin `YouCompleteMe`. It almost works perfectly, but when I type `.`, the completer doesn't start. When I type `->` the completer works correctly. How I can I have the completer start after I put a `.` on a class object?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @StunBrick sorry about my English) I want to activate completer when I put `.` after some class object.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your problem, but I can't fix it for you. I've made an edit suggestion though. See if it still asks the same question you want to ask.